# Decrypting IllegalBlockSizeException

Tags: java, encryption

The following code is based on cryptography.
Inside my constructor, I initialise this:

```
try{
        //To generate the secret key
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
        sKey = keyGen.generateKey();
        //Initialize the cipher instance to use DES algorithm, ECB mode,
        //and PKCS#5 padding scheme.
        cipherObj = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    }
    catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae){nsae.printStackTrace();

    }
    catch(NoSuchPaddingException nspe){nspe.printStackTrace();}
```

I have this code under a button called Encrypt and its actually working

```
try{
    //Initialize the cipher with secret key to encrypt the data.
    cipherObj.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sKey);
    //Read the data into byte array
    byte[] textToEncrypt = txtTobeEncrypted.getText().getBytes();
    //To encrypt the data
    byte[] encryptedData = cipherObj.doFinal(textToEncrypt);
    //Display the encrypted data
    String encryptedText = new String(encryptedData);
    txtEncryptOutput.setText(encryptedText);
}
catch(InvalidKeyException ivkey){ivkey.printStackTrace();}
catch(BadPaddingException bpe){bpe.printStackTrace();}
catch(IllegalBlockSizeException ilbs){ilbs.printStackTrace();}
```

But the following code which is under Decrypt button is not working

```
try{
    //Initialize the cipher with secret key to encrypt the data.
    cipherObj.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sKey);
    //Read the data into byte array
    byte[] textToDecrypt = txtEncryptOutput.getText().getBytes();
    //To decrypt the data
    byte[] plainData = cipherObj.doFinal(textToDecrypt);
    //Display the encrypted data
    String thePlainText = new String(plainData);
    txtDecrypt.setText(thePlainText);
}
catch(InvalidKeyException ivkey){ivkey.printStackTrace();}
catch(BadPaddingException bpe){bpe.printStackTrace();}
catch(IllegalBlockSizeException ilbs){ilbs.printStackTrace();}
```

the Exception am getting is as follow:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:750)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESCipher.engineDoFinal(DESCipher.java:314)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2086)
at cryptography.FileEncryption.cmdDecryptActionPerformed(FileEncryption.java:209)
```

So please can anyone explain why I am getting this exception?

Comment: May be this link can help you.. [JCE Encryption – Data Encryption Standard (DES) Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jce-encryption-data-encryption-standard-des-tutorial/)

Answer (score 3):

You can't decode a sequence of random bytes to a `String`. Most character encodings don't map every byte or byte sequence to a character; these will replace information with a � (replacement character).

Instead, convert the cipher text to a printable string and back again using a suitable encoding like Base-64.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting this exception because the length of `txtEncryptOutput.getText().getBytes()` is not a multiple of 8.

You can confirm this by inspecting it under the debugger, or outputting the length to the terminal your logging system.